# Node.js : which keys in req.body are present in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, schema, httprequest

When I get a POST request, I want to get the entries whose keys are present in my model's schema. For example, if my 'user' model's schema consists of 'name' and 'email' keys, then as I iterate over req.body, I only want to get values for the 'name' and 'email' fields. How do I do that?

Comment: "I only want to set values for the 'name' and 'email' fields". Do you mean 'get' not 'set'?

Comment: Whoops, typo. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wanting to have an unspecified set of keys to query mongo with, and to only return data for those keys.

If that is in fact the case, using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) with lodash/underscore:

```
var keys = _.keys(req.body);

User.find(req.body).select(keys.join(' ')).lean().exec(function(err, user {
  if (err)
    throw err;

  res.send(user);
}):
```

That's assuming certain things about the req.body object and how keys match up to the schema.

Answer (score 0):

if you have form fields like,

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
```

then instead of iterating over req.body, you can,

```
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
```

Comment: This is for a rest api, there is no front end. My use case is a db service, which takes in the schema and the request body, and sets the parameters in the schema with the values in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that retrieves fields from the body of a post request, using **express** with the **bodyParser()** middleware :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.bodyParser());
... // other middleware
// Routes
app.post('/path', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.user.name;
    var email = req.body.user.email;
    ... // some more code
});
```

Hope that helps.